# Apache RewriteRule to redirect domain to subfolder leads to Redirect loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have almost had it with mod_rewrite. I have taken out **every other** rewrite statement (except for `RewriteEngine on`...although I should because that is clearly the problem) and this still doesn't work. I have included my entire virtual host file so hopefully someone can tell me what's wrong here. I want to type the following and be redirected (internally ie. not visible in address bar) like so

1. `www.example.com` **--->** `www.example/files/main/index.php`
2. `www.business.example.com` **--->** `www.example/files/business/index.php`
3. `www.tech.example.com` **--->** `www.example/files/tech/index.php`
4. `www.sports.example.com` **--->** `www.example/files/sports/index.php`
5. ...

I tried tackling both 1 and 2-5+ at the same time and it was a disaster. So I gave up on 2-5+ temporarily, and just tried to get 1 working, and no matter what I do I get a redirect loop. Obviously, I would prefer a perfect answer to copy paste, but I would even settle with someone explaining just why mod_rewrite insists on favoring redirect loops. Thank you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /files/main

ServerAdmin www-data@example.com
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php filename.html index.cgi index.pl default.htm

<Directory /var/www>
suPHP_Engine on
suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /etc/php5/cgi/
AllowOverride None
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

LogLevel warn 
LogFormat "%v %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" comonvhost
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log comonvhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I do not see an `[R]` flag in your rewrite rules, then why are you being redirected? Can you look at the browser's net inspector (F12 in Chrome/Firebug) and post the requested URL and the redirected URL(s)?

Comment: @SalmanA All it says is http://www.example.com/ -- GET --403 Forbidden --text/html

Comment: 403 forbidden is not the same as a redirect loop.

Comment: @SalmanA sorry, I changed one tiny thing, and now I have a different problem. Let me recreate the original conditions

Comment: @SalmanA I am running into problems recreating it. That's not to say the problem has been fixed, just that it has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the mod_rewrite documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

If you're fed up with mod_rewrite, this could just be the thing. (Do you want to redirect those websites to the new URL's visibly, or rewrite invisibly?)

I am not able to reproduce the problem you are having. My setup has quite a few VirtualHost entries and Directory entries, with quite a bit of rewriting going on.

I added a rule much like yours to my main VirtualHost.  Now you should be aware that this will match nothing, because a request for the document root is `/` not the empty string.

```
RewriteRule ^$ /foo/bar
```

I did not get a redirect loop when accessing the site; it was simply ignored. Then I changed it to:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /foo/bar
```

Restarted the server, went to it and got the old *The requested URL /var/www/foo/bar was not found on this server.*  No loop.

There is something else in your setup. Maybe the URL's you are rewriting to to have a local `.htaccess` that is triggering a loop. (But how they are being rewritten to by a match for `^$` beats me.)